# Data split in PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgresql

We have data like this in PostgreSQL 11.17

```
create table t1 (oldattributes varchar(1000),newattributes varchar(1000))
insert into t1 values ('inTime=10-Aug-2023 09:24,outTime=,totalHours=,payCodeId=RegularPay,outType=,DEPARTMENT=14,supApprovalFlag=F','inTime=10-Aug-2023 09:24,outTime=10-Aug-2023 17:00,totalHours=27343,payCodeId=,outType=SCAN,supApprovalFlag=F')
```

expected output as

```
oldattributes                           newattributes 

inTime=10-Aug-2023 09:24                inTime=10-Aug-2023 09:24
outTime=                                outTime=10-Aug-2023 17:00
totalHours=                             totalHours=27343
payCodeId=RegularPay                    payCodeId=
outType=                                outType=SCAN
DEPARTMENT=14                           [NULL]
supApprovalFlag=F                       supApprovalFlag=F
```

This can be done using regexp_split_to_table function as below

```
select regexp_split_to_table(oldattributes , E',') AS oldattributes,
       regexp_split_to_table(newattributes , E',') AS newattributes
from t1
```

The issue with above query is that DEPARTMENT attribute is not there in newattributes column.
Expected to be null values as shown in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a full join of the tables returned by `regexp_split_to_table()`:

```
SELECT s.e1, s.e2
FROM t1
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      (SELECT o.e1, n.e2
       FROM regexp_split_to_table(t1.oldattributes, ',') AS o(e1)
          FULL JOIN regexp_split_to_table(t1.newattributes, ',') AS n(e2)
             ON split_part(o.e1, '=', 1) = split_part(n.e2, '=', 1)
      ) AS s;

            e1            │            e2             
══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════
 DEPARTMENT=14            │ ∅
 inTime=10-Aug-2023 09:24 │ inTime=10-Aug-2023 09:24
 outTime=                 │ outTime=10-Aug-2023 17:00
 outType=                 │ outType=SCAN
 payCodeId=RegularPay     │ payCodeId=
 supApprovalFlag=F        │ supApprovalFlag=F
 totalHours=              │ totalHours=27343
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks you Laurenz. it helped me. I've a doubt. what is this alias **AS o(e1)** . In general, alias will be as AS e1. But what is AS o(e1)?

Comment: That is an alias for a table expression that gives a name to the table and all its columns.